# Why is SSH not honoring my authorized keys?

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-12.04, ssh-keys, authorized-keys

I have 2 laptops at home, both running Ubuntu 12.04 (Desktop), and both using the same NetGear wifi router. I used a technique called "MAC binding" on one of the machines so that the router always assigns it the same 192.168.1.52 IP address every time it tries to connect to the Internet. (*Unrelated: MAC binding just means configuring the router to always bind a specific MAC address to a specific IP.*)

So now, I have 1 laptop that always gets assigned a random IP in the 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.50 range, and 1 laptop (my "build server") that always get assigned 192.168.1.52.

I am trying to write some bash script that I will run on the "client" laptop (the random IP machine) that will `ssh` into the build server (192.169.1.52 machine); hence the necessity for the build server to have a "dedicated" IP from inside my LAN. I don't want to have to explicitly feed these bash scripts a password, so I followed the instructions in [this article here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and) to generate SSH keys. Specifically, I:

1. Generate SSH keys on my client laptop (producing an `id_rsa.pub` file)
2. I `scp`'d the `id_rsa.pub` file to my build server, and `cat`'d it into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. I verified that my client laptop's SSH key now exists inside the `authorized_keys` file on the build server.
3. I closed the terminal on my client laptop and then reopened a new one, just for good measure (in case Linux needs that in order to restart anything, etc.)
4. I then tried to SSH into the build server, and **am still being prompted for a password!**

What's going on here? Why is SSH on my build server not honoring the authorized keys from my client laptop? Do I need to restart anything on the build server (`sshd`, etc.)? Have I missed any crucial steps here? How to start troubleshooting? Thanks in advance!

**Update**:
Apparently Ubuntu doesn't have a `/var/log/secure.log`, but *does* have a `/var/log/auth.log`. When I tail this log on the build server, and then attempt to SSH into the build server from my client laptop, here's what happens:

1. I run `ssh myuser@buildserver` from the client laptop
2. I am prompted for a password.
3. As soon as I enter the password, I see the following output in the build server's `auth.log` file:

```
May 21 12:02:07 buildserver sshd[28930]: error: RSA_public_decrypt failed: error:0407006A:lib(4):func(112):reason(106)
May 21 12:02:10 buildserver sshd[28930]: pam_sm_authenticate: Called
May 21 12:02:10 buildserver sshd[28930]: pam_sm_authenticate: username = [myuser]
May 21 12:02:10 buildserver sshd[28930]: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/myuser is already mounted
May 21 12:02:10 buildserver sshd[28930]: Accepted password for myuser from 192.168.1.3 port 39821 ssh2
May 21 12:02:10 buildserver sshd[28930]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myuser by (uid=0)
May 21 12:02:10 buildserver sshd[29003]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.3: 11: disconnected by user
May 21 12:02:10 buildserver sshd[28930]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user myuser
```

Something that maybe I should have mentioned: on both machines (the client laptop and my build server, the username/account name is `myuser`) - could Linux be getting confused because of the same username on both machines?

Comment: The generic term for "MAC Binding" is a *persistent DHCP reservation*.

Comment: Does your public key start with `ssh-rsa` or `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----` ?

Comment: The fiirst, `ssh-rsa`...is that my private key?

Comment: No, that's just how my key entries are, but tools always seem to generate the latter kind, and I always convert them. See my answer.

Comment: Are you using `ssh-agent` to manage your private key? Does it work if you use `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0 ssh buildserver` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First step: restart ssh with `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`. Also, ensure that the permissions on the authorized_users file is correct. To verify, use `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and ensure it's owned by the user you're logging in as.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan C (+1) - I tried both suggstions: I restarted `ssh` (via `sudo service ssh stop` then `sudo service ssh start`), and then I changed the permissions on `authorized_keys` from 700 to 750. Please note that I restarted a service called `ssh`, **not** `sshd` like you suggested. There doesn't seem to be a service called `sshd` installed on my build server (remember its an Ubuntu desktop), so *could that be my problem?* If so, what's the fix? If not, anything else you can think of? Thanks again!

Comment: The desktop portion doesn't matter (since it's just the GUI that makes it a "desktop"). Does the `/var/log/secure.log` have anything referencing the key?

Comment: @TicketMonster - You also need to `cat id.pub >> authorized_keys2`. Depending on your ssh protocols enabled, you need both `authorized_keys` and `authorized_keys2`. Restarting the service is unnecessary, unless you change ssh/sshd configurations.

Comment: Thanks again @NathanC (+1) - please see my update at the bottom of my original question and let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks @nerdwaller (+1) - I'll give it a try in the meantime. One thing though, if what you say is true, why do none of the "How to use SSH keys"-type tutorials mention `authorized_keys2`? I'm a little skeptical, because isn't `id.pub` my private key? Why would I want the build server to have my private key?!? Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster `id.pub` is your `pub`lic key. `id_rsa` should be your private key. `authorized_keys2` is not strictly necessary; My ubuntu boxes work just fine with my keys in `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry guys I'm confusing myself here: when I used `ssh-keygen` it made 2 files: `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. The `id_rsa.pub` is what is installed on the build server (which got there by me scp'ing it and then cat'ing it).

Comment: Looks like the public key is corrupted. Try copying it over again. If needed, regenerate your keypair and start from scratch.

Comment: @TicketMonster For the record, `.ssh` should be `700`, and `authorized_keys` should be `600`. What happens if you use those permissions?

Comment: @DarthAndroid Ah, my permissions were incorrect. Updated my answer with it.

Comment: I regenerated the keys like @NathanC suggested - and now it works! Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 5):

For me, deleting id_rsa.pub helped (I was using ~/.ssh/id_rsa key). This was caused, because id_rsa.pub was not matching my id_rsa key.

Answer (score 1):

What format is your public key in?

I find a lot of tools generate keys like this:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "1024-bit RSA, converted from OpenSSH by me@example.com"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEA1on8gxCGJJWSRT4uOrR13mUaUk0hRf4RzxSZ1zRb
YYFw8pfGesIFoEuVth4HKyF8k1y4mRUnYHP1XNMNMJl1JcEArC2asV8sHf6zSPVffozZ
5TT4SfsUu/iKy9lUcCfXzwre4WWZSXXcPff+EHtWshahu3WzBdnGxm5Xoi89zcE=
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

And my `authorized_keys` file always contained the key like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEA1on8gxCGJJWSRT4uOrR13mUaUk0hRf4RzxSZ1zRbYYFw8pfGesIFoEuVth4HKyF8k1y4mRUnYHP1XNMNMJl1JcEArC2asV8sHf6zSPVffozZ5TT4SfsUu/iKy9lUcCfXzwre4WWZSXXcPff+EHtWshahu3WzBdnGxm5Xoi89zcE=
```

(The public key concatenated together all on one line)

Comment: Thanks @Darth Android (+1) - my public key starts `ssh-rsa`, not the `---- BEGIN...` style. What does this tell you?

Comment: Just that this isn't the answer. Sorry :(